# Multi-Page form using AJAX, Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am currently trying to create a multi-page form that uses both jQuery and PHP together to error check.  The issue I have is that I am relatively new to jQuery, and don't know how to move to the second form rather than just display a success message from a PHP array.

I have used the example from ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwExOhVaUyk ) as my guide. Its an example that uses the `ajax_submit` to process when form is ready, if it is successful the PHP script runs and error checks and then throws back a successful message.

I do not want the success message.  I want if successful to move to second page, but not sure how to do this.

```
The following is the ajax code

// make our ajax request to the server
function submitForm(formData) {
    $.ajax({    
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'feedback.php?images=' + encs.toString(),      
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 7000,
        success: function(data) {           

            if(data.error == true){

            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error').html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');                                      

            } else{
                $("#rightcolumn").fadeOut(500, function(){

                    //NOTE THIS IS THE LINE THAT BRINGS BACK THE SUCCESSFUL MESSAGE STORED IN data.msg (taken from array in php file).

                    $("#rightcolumn").append().html(data.msg).fadeIn(500);
                });

            }



        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<p>There was an<strong> ' + errorThrown +
                              '</strong> error due to a<strong> ' + textStatus +
                              '</strong> condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');           
        }
```

THE PHP

```
$return['error'] = false;
            $return['msg'] = "<html>";
            $return['msg'] .="<head>"; 
            $return['msg'] .="</head>"; 
            $return['msg'] .= "<div id=\"coverrightb\">";
            $return['msg'] .= "<body>";
            $return['msg'] .= "<h2>Successful Registration <img id=\"thumbsup\" src=\"images/icons/thumbsup.png\" alt=\"ThumbsUp\" /></h2>";
            $return['msg'] .= "<br />"; 
            $return['msg'] .= "<p>Thanks for registering " .$firstname .". Your details are below.</p>";
            $return['msg'] .= "<br />"; 
echo json_encode($return);
```

I want it to simply move on to second page, not sure how to do this.  Would be really grateful for some guidance.  I'm learning PHP and jQuery but been stuck on this for several weeks.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect users by changing `window.location` to the desired URL:

```
    success: function(data) {           
        if(data.error == true){
            $('#response').removeClass().addClass('error').html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');
        } else{
            $("#rightcolumn").fadeOut(500, function(){

                //NOTE THIS IS THE LINE THAT BRINGS BACK THE SUCCESSFUL MESSAGE STORED IN data.msg (taken from array in php file).
                window.location = 'form-page-2.php';//note that this line will stop running the JavaScript on this page, so the next line will not run

                $("#rightcolumn").append().html(data.msg).fadeIn(500);
            });

        }
    },
```

Another solution would be to load the new form into the same page via AJAX so the user doesn't have to load a whole new page:

```
    success: function(data) {           
        if(data.error == true){
            $('#response').removeClass().addClass('error').html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');
        } else{
            $("#rightcolumn").fadeOut(500, function(){

                //NOTE THIS IS THE LINE THAT BRINGS BACK THE SUCCESSFUL MESSAGE STORED IN data.msg (taken from array in php file).

                $("#rightcolumn").load('form-page-2.php #only-the-form', function () {
                    $(this).fadeIn(500);
                });
            });

        }
    },
```

Some documentation for ya:

- `window.location`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location
- `.load()`: http://api.jquery.com/load

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback.  I have a three page form.  Form a) basic user details, b) more about them, and c) hobbies/interests.  At present i can only get the first form to be submitted successfully with the success message shown.  I will try your solution and post back the second form. I hope this works, but i think the php may need changing.  I will let you know.  Thankyou for now

Comment: @skippy so you will want to chain the redirects. When validating the `a` form, if succesful then redirect the user to `b`, and from `b` to `c`. This can be hard-coded into different page or if you want to do it dynamically you could use your PHP script to determine which form has been submitted and return an identifier for the next form as the server response (so your AJAX call will get this information in its `success` callback function and you can dynamically load the proper form for the user).

Comment: Thanks alot Jasper, after a month of trying your one line of code worked a treat and had helped me to understand how to use this between the second and third form!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too clear on what you want but if you just want to redirect to another page with another form, then on the callback of the ajax request, use the `window.location` javascript redirect.